# How do I change the radius of sphere in vpython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, vpython

```
from visual import *
s=[]
r=0.1
f=open('G:\Dropbox\Programming\Fortran\MolecularDynamics\Source\pos.dat','r')
box(pos=[1,1,1],length=2,width=2,height=2,opacity=0.5)
for line in f:
    rate(1)
    row = line.split()
    x = float(row[0])
    y = float(row[1])
    z = float(row[2])
    s.append(sphere(pos=[x,y,z],rad=r))
```

In the above code, the radius of the sphere doesn't change when I change the value of r. What am I doing wrong?

Here are the contents of pos.dat

```
  0.76425066770083916        1.0636929975958958        1.1172529144364949     
   1.5493877083479954        1.8739841784589457       0.32294665232964315     
   1.7226925707051988        1.2935288113975998       0.82842705941539108     
   1.1157571132788351        1.6032073165018330       0.47281352901565676     
  0.85641201180922688       0.43381700408239521       0.87082052348215733     
   1.2295464749283869        1.6343067967959193        1.8621538204952262     
  0.24459026475960810       0.48469706447047489       0.66260850683935280     
   9.7846721099904554E-002   1.0883378789613212        1.0974266698879096     
   1.3217953491654058        1.2185744544458481       0.46992237251202784     
  0.93138446212988923       0.17350531672748493       0.46661784215632274     
   1.0043589622107352        1.9359078801899188        1.9320966852700339     
   1.2058561745199539       0.68518208899112198       0.36442977608095561     
   1.6757663457868546       0.10346775928039831        1.4283142254811065     
   1.5569448852911780        1.7586288480611603        1.9266600727629331     
   1.9325159921796258       0.33110561878449962        1.7581902883579656     
  0.63844388963707432       0.34815817893985024       0.91100666305761346     
   1.9482563908931441        1.5574645513006116        1.9109607990747766     
  0.49479122111175244       0.33686742568910266       0.10389548165695972     
  0.18416224004253112       0.43553604681424996        8.6043504475411980E-002
   7.9873689634088141E-002  0.73068476142567929        8.4607849131498103E-002
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when I change the value of r". You are not changing it in a code, it's assigned only once.

Comment: @RafałŁużyński When I change it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The argument of sphere should be `radius`, not `rad`.
This is the correct working code.

```
from visual import *
s=[]
r=0.1
f=open('G:\Dropbox\Programming\Fortran\MolecularDynamics\Source\pos.dat','r')
box(pos=[1,1,1],length=2,width=2,height=2,opacity=0.5)
for line in f:
    rate(1)
    row = line.split()
    x = float(row[0])
    y = float(row[1])
    z = float(row[2])
    s.append(sphere(pos=[x,y,z],radius=r))
```